# Minimize sub-expression in sublime text regex search and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I am trying to replace

```
<div id="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Logo.png" width="205" height="50"  alt="logo"/></a><a class="menu-hider"></a></div>
```

with

```
<div id="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="{{ asset( 'images/Logo.png' }}" width="205" height="50"  alt="logo"/></a><a class="menu-hider"></a></div>
```

in Sublime text. Based on the docs I figured this would work
search

```
src=\"(.*)\"
```

replace

```
src=\"{{ asset('$1') }}\"
```

However instead of Sublime search catching

```
src="images/Logo.png"
```

it catches the longest possible sub-expression and finds the last occurence of \"

```
src="images/Logo.png" width="205" height="50"  alt="logo"/></a><a class="menu-hider"
```

this is instead of the first which is what I'm expecting. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `.*` is greedy, meaning it'll match as much as possible until it reaches `\"`. Change it to the lazy form by adding `?`:

```
src=\"(.*?)\"
         ^
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pZ9yZ2)

or use a negated class:

```
src=\"([^\"]*)\"
       ^^^^^
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU3wN3)

The latter will match any character except `"` so there's no way it'll match a `"`.

Note: I don't remember the requirement to escape quotes in ST2. I can't test it right now, but it should be working fine without being escaped.

Comment: Negated class should be the way to go! =D And actually you don't need to escape the double quotes in Sublime Text, right?

Comment: @justhalf I believe that too, but I don't have ST installed right now and can't download it right now (switched OS a while back and haven't got all my installs yet :( ). But yes, I would go for negated classes all the way!